# Movie Identification: 80s Scifi/Comedy, Guy travels to a planet full of very stupid people

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to find a movie that I have very very vague memories of. It is about either a family, or a just a guy, who ends up on this different planet. Nearly everyone is really **really** dumb.

The planet is ruled by one main bad guy, though there are rebels. At one point the main guys finds some of the rebels, and they are dressed in giant bird costumes, which our hero points out wouldn't fool anyone because there are no human sized birds.

The only other person who is intelligent is the commander of the planetary emperor's army, I think.

I think this was a 70s/80s movie, but I'm not sure. Ring any bells with anyone?

**Edit**:

There may also have been a scene of the hero being thrown down this garbage shute, or something, and grabbing this thing to hang on from, then climbing back up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question was already asked an answered. It's Mom and Dad Save the World
[What movie or tv show has a tribe of "bird men" outside a walled city in the desert?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111489/what-movie-or-tv-show-has-a-tribe-of-bird-men-outside-a-walled-city-in-the-des)

> Sirk: "We wear these masks to disguise ourselves as birds."
>   (The tribe starts clucking.)
>
> Dick: "Ah, excuse me. Do you really have birds this size on your planet?"
>
> Sirk: "No."

Comment: That's it! Thanks, mate.